# Tkinter GUI implemented with Separate Python file with functions

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, pygui

I am having problem with having a GUI interface to be implemented via a second file which just contains the file to read, plots made and some new functions to be evaluated based on that.

I am trying to create a GUI application using Tkinter. The way I am doing is as follows. I have a background script (say Background.py) which has two functions. Function X loads a data file, does some calculations and outputs a graph. The way I want to trigger this is via a GUI script in another file (GUI.py) which opens a panel with a button and when I click the button the function X in file Background.py should be evaluated and a plot should be shown. Once I check the plot, I can hit another button to close the plot and terminate the function X.  Now I can choose to click another button to trigger the function Y in the file Background.py. These button should allow me to input three values, which should be the input to the function Y in the file Background.py. Once I hit this button, it should trigger the function Y and do what it it asks it to do. Now at the end, after that I can hit the button to close the gui.

How can I do this?. A general rough idea will be helpful.

I have put an example as much as I can:( at least the skeleton of the code)
I have a background file say (Background.py) and gui file ( say GUI.py)

**Background.py**

```
import numpy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas

def progX():
     df = pd.read (myfile)

     ##df.stats # doing something and generating a plot from the file

    plt.boxplot(df['col'])

    plt.show()



def progY(y1, y2,y3):

    ## get the y1, y2, y3 from the GUI interface which the user has entered 

    #run a code...  and generate an output file
```

**GUI.py**

```
import Background as bg   
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class GUI ():

    def create widgets(self):
        #....

    def create_panel2(self):
        #create buttons
        panel1 = ...
        btn1 = Button(panel1, text="yyyyy", command=bg.progA)
        btn1.pack() 

    def create_panel2(self):
        #create buttons
        panel2 = ...
        btn2 = Button(panel1, text="yyyyy", command=bg.progB)
        btn2.pack() 

All_Entries = []

window = Tk()
D=GUI(window)
window.mainloop()
runprogram1 = bg.progX()
runprogram2 = bg.probY(x, y, z)
```

My question is now, does the above makes sense? How can I call the background functions from the GUI?  The statements runprogram1 & runprogram2 are definitely not correct, How can I implement that. Also how will I ensure that I call the proram Y in Background once I have close the output from the program X?

I guess the questions makes sense. I am new to GUI and having hard time working this out, which I need to. any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is your *Background.py* correct? I think you are missing `'` on `plt.boxplot(df['col])`.

Comment: Yes Black Thunder you are correct. I updated that. But that was not the issue. My problems are much deeper. Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody answer this. Even some basic help may be beneficial..

Comment: Just to make sure are you aware that your code after the mainloop will never run until the GUI is closed.

Comment: Yes.. Nut I am wanting to ask if I am going in the righ direction

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `progA` == `progX`, and `progB` == `progY`?

As your code is currently structured, some function in the GUI needs to get y1, y2 and y3 from a widget (`Entry()`, presumably), and pass to `progY`. `progY` can't fetch that info, b/c progY isn't aware of the widgets in the GUI. Get those values in the GUI class by binding the button to another function that 1) calls `.get()` on the `Entry()` widget, and then 2) passes those values to progY.

Make your Entry boxes in the GUI:

```
e1 = Entry(panel1)
e2 = Entry(panel1)
e3 = Entry(panel1)
self.entries = (e1, e2, e3)
for e in self.entries:
    e.pack()
```

Make a function that gets values and calls `progY` in the GUI:

```
def get_entries_call_y(self):
    e = [x.get() for x in self.entries]
    bd.progY(e[0], e[1], e[2])
```

Bind your button to `get_entries_call_y` (not to `bd.progY`):

```
btn2 = Button(panel1, text="yyyyy", command=get_entries_call_y)
```

If you'd like advice on structuring a GUI program in general, try adhering (as best you can) to a standard user interface architecture like model-view-controller (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller). The solution I described above should make your program work, but the way you've structured your program isn't really a good way to do it for a lot of reasons. Learning MVC will help you organize what task should go into what function/class/file, give you a logical framework for adding features and improving your code, and allow you to create new GUI programs more efficiently.

Or at least that's what I got out of learning MVC.

Comment: Wonderful.. Thanks a lot mRotten. I will go through it and restructure and keep you posted.